# Geoserver locking up

Tags: geoserver

I have an instance of geoserver running on tomcat on centos.
It is frequently locking up, and whilst the load average on the server is only 3.5 and you can log into the command line, you cannot request any tiles nor log into the admin section.

It seems that too many requests from openlayers stops http access.
How can I get to the bottom of this issue?

Comment: look in the log file and see what it says

Comment: Also, when it locks up, try using the jstack tool to get a stack trace, and share it here. See also: http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/production/troubleshooting.html#jstack